# SQLite in ASP.NET Core uses more and more RAM with every call

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, sqlite-net

Queries that return a lot of data from an SQLite database use RAM that is never released. The RAM use is many times larger than the database and eventually leads to Windows out of memory errors and instability.

This example using the ASP.NET Core Web Application template in Visual Studio 2019 shows the problem. I replace the default `WeatherForecastController` with this code.

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<int> GetAsync()
        {
            // create a 450MB database for testing (on first run only).
            if (System.IO.File.Exists("BigDatabase.db") == false) {
                using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("BigDatabase.db"))
                {
                    db.CreateTable<NumbersAndText>();
                    List<NumbersAndText> ListOfMadeUpDataToInsertIntoDatabase = new List<NumbersAndText>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        NumbersAndText nat = new NumbersAndText()
                        {
                            Number = i,
                            BigBlockOfText = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Lots of text repeated over and over again.", 1000))
                        };
                        ListOfMadeUpDataToInsertIntoDatabase.Add(nat);
                    }
                    db.InsertAll(ListOfMadeUpDataToInsertIntoDatabase);
                }
            }

            // Take a lot of data from the database.
            // The process uses 500MB the first time the controller is fired. 900MB after the second time. 1.2GB, 1.3GB, etc...
            // After 15 calls the process is using 3.4GB of RAM.
            // Garbage Collection reduces this to around 2GB, at which point RAM use is stable. But this is now x5 the size of the database in RAM.
            // With a larger example this quickly fills all RAM and triggers the Windows out of memory killer. 
            List<NumbersAndText> Orgs;
            using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("BigDatabase.db"))
            {
                Orgs = new List<NumbersAndText>(db.Table<NumbersAndText>().Take(5000));
            }

            // return just the numbers
            return Orgs.Select(x => x.Number);            
        }
    }
    public class NumbersAndText
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string BigBlockOfText { get; set; }
    }
```

In this example I use the [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library to work with the SQLite database, but the problem is reproducible using EFCore.

I am pretty sure that I am doing something very dumb. But I can't figure out what.

Comment: Use Visual Studio's built-in profiling tools to take and analyse memory snapshots: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks Ian. Unfortunately I've done a lot of that and it wasn't much help. Both native, mixed, and native & mixed memory diagnostics lead me to the same place. I compare the heaps before and after each call but there is never anywhere near enough extra objects to explain this.

Comment: @thomasforth have you got a fix for this ?